# What would be the steps to compare 2 videos of a room taken at different times and detect what has changed? (furniture, colors or damaged things)?

Tags: video, video-processing, detection, difference

If I take a video of a room and another one 6 months after, I would like to get snapshot before/after of what has changed.
As the 2 videos will not be taken exactly the same way with the same luminosity or angles, how can I first get my program to detect the frames that are about the same space in the room and then compare them to check if there are changes. These changes must not be about luminosity or orientation.

I would like to know if such a program is feasible and what would be the différents steps and library I can use.